# Power Apps - Reset Form Fields

Tags: powerapps

I am relatively new to PowerApps and am having a bit of an issue with the form resetting, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

- I have set up the form to write back to SharePoint online
- I have tried putting the formula Button1.Pressed on the reset field of the various text boxes but then the data is being wiped out before it is stored in SharePoint, however when selecting a new form it is providing me with an empty form.

I would need to be able to press the submit button, have the data stored and the next time I press the button for a new form I would need it to be clear of information.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you used a form in PowerApps you can submit your form using SubmitForm(Form1) and to reset it ResetForm(Form1).  Field by field would be something like Reset(TextInput1).